# Which test in this case ? Friedman not possible

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, feature-selection, friedman-test, mlr

I have done a benchmarking of multiple learners on multiple tasks with nested CV (inner loop : CV 3F, and outer loop : CV 3F). My datas have 1052 observations and each task have 10-12 features.
I obtained the mean AUC and a standard deviation like this :

[image]

I want to compare the algorithms between them and I don't feel like the Friedman test will be useful because all the tasks are not independent, it corresponds to multiple features selection on the same dataset...

How to interpret it then to select the best algorithm and the best features selection technic ?

EDIT : I add the results of the Friedman test post hoc in case if you want it with the critical difference :

[image]

[image]

EDIT 2 : I think there is no problem with this, since I want to test my models on this dataset only. If I use multiple tasks with more or less different features but all from this same dataset, it causes no problem. The goal is to prove that this algorithm in particular is better on this particular dataset...